# Getting error "SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure" when storing data in localStorage of UIWebView

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiwebview, xamarin.forms

I am developing one sample **Xamarin.Forms** Application and in this application I'm using **WebView for tyro payment gateway integration** and also create WebViewRenderer for store data in localStorage of UIWebView. and I'm getting security error (**SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure**). 
Tyro payment gateway web url is "https://iclient.test.tyro.com".

Please have a look below my code and help me

```
string subkey = "window.localStorage.setItem('webTta.integrationKey','integrationKey')";
string key ="try { "+subkey +"; } catch (e) {  alert(e);  }";
IntegrationKey = _uiWebView.EvaluateJavascript(key);
```

[image]

Comment: I think the localstorage might be missing. Could you check what the following prints if you call it in the javascript:

    console.log(window.localStorage == null)

Also could you tell which version of iOS are you running? There seems to be issues in WKWebview localStorage with some versions at least.

Comment: @hamalaiv Thank you for your reply. I have try your suggestion and it is not working for me. My iOS version is iOS 10.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course console.log doesn't work on the device. You could try `alert("localStorage is null: " + window.localStorage == null)`. This would give you an alert saying if the local storage is available or not.

Comment: @hamalaiv , Yes i know console.log is not working on device. That's why i tried following code `string subkey = string.Format("alert('result: ' + localStorage == null);"  string key ="try { "+subkey +"; } catch (e) { alert(e); }";  _webView.EvaluateJavascript(key);`  And also try your suggested code, still getting same error. I think, something is not allow to access localStorage in UIWebView. Do I need to add/configure any permission description in info.plist file? or other configuration in app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My issue is solved. This error was occurring by storing data before loading page. I solved this issue by call EvaluateJavascript method after loading a page.
If you try to call an EvaluateJavascript method in blank WebView then it is also occurring.